# Powershell update on windows server having SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Can we upgrade the Powershell to the latest version on Windows server 2008R2 standard hosting a SharePoint 2010 farm ?

Will the farm have any impact?

Does it require any prerequisites before upgrading the PowerShell? The current version is 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can freely update it to the latest supported version. SharePoint 2010 will continue using the .NET 2.0 framework. In addition, your SharePoint Management Shell shortcut must have `-Version 2.0` tacked onto the run line in order to function. Any PowerShell window you open that needs access to SharePoint cmdlets/SSOM must also have `-Version 2.0` as a start switch.